# Python virtual environment error: Module not found error for flask and spacy libraries

Tags: python, flask, anaconda, conda, spacy

I am developing a web application using flask and spacy libraries for which I have created a virtual environment using the following command: `conda create -n mylgappflaskenv python=3.6`  which gets created and then I activate my virtual environment using the following command `activate mylgappflaskenv`  then to install spacy and flask I execute `pip install spacy` and `pip install flask`  one after the another and they get installed successfully. then I have created a new file name app.py with the following code

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("Apple is looking at buying U.K. startup for $1 billion")
for token in doc:
    print(token.text)
```

on running this file I am getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 16, in <module>
     import spacy
ImportError: cannot import name 'spacy'
```

steps

```
step1: conda create -n mylgapp2 python=3.6
step2: conda activate mylgapp2
step3: conda install -c conda-forge spacy
step4: python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm --> it gives error
step5: conda install -c anaconda flask

step6: write code: 

import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("Apple is looking at buying U.K. startup for $1 billion")
for token in doc:
    print(token.text)

step 7: conda run app.py
```

what am I missing, how can I resolve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a line in your flask `app.py` that is attempting to import `from spacy import spacy` if so I'm not sure that's a valid spacy import.

EDIT : run `python app.py` instead of `conda run app.py`

Comment: No, its just import spacy. moreover, I just want to confirm one thing that Can we use spacy libraries in a web application?

Comment: Yes, you definitely can as I've built a small service based entirely off of flask and spacy. Have you also installed the language model `en_core_web_sm` itself through the command line  ?

Comment: run `conda activate mylgappflaskenv` in your command line just to make sure that you are actually in the right environment also.  Your terminal/cmd prompt should looks like `( mylgappflaskenv) C:\Users\....`

Comment: Yes, I had tried to install the language model but it had given me an error. I have updated the steps in question detail that I am doing.

Comment: I see you are using `conda run app.py`  I'm not sure that does what you think it does. Instead try `python app.py` making sure that your conda environment is activated and that you are in the correct directory.

Comment: can you please share detail steps you used while developing your service.

Comment: I created a conda environment specifically for the project. Activated that environment. Then ran `conda install package-name` for both spacy and flask. With spacy installed I then downloaded the right langauge model via `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`. My spacy logic was in another file than my flask `app.py` but that shouldn't make much of a difference. I imported the functions from the spacy service into the flask app. Since you haven't initialised an actual flask app yet `flask run` isn't going to do anything for you, but that's what I did to run the service.

Comment: I am such a stupid. you are right I ran the code with python app.py and it worked

Comment: Oh brilliant. Glad it was a simple fix, could you mark this as answered ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using conda virtual environment manager, it's recommended to use conda package installation tool, which is *conda*, to install a library. In your case, it's better to install flask and spacy libraries with conda which are;

```
    $ conda install -c anaconda flask
    $ conda install -c conda-forge spacy
    $ python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

These are the references [flask-anaconda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/flask) and spacy [usage](https://spacy.io/usage)

Comment: I had tried this also but still, I get the same issue

Answer (score 0):

The steps I follow to create a conda environment;

- conda create -n myenv python=3.6
- conda activate myenv

This step shows me the environment name in my line also

```
    $ (myenv)
```

You can install required libraries after you make sure you are in the correct virtual environment

```
    $ (myenv) conda install -c anaconda flask
    $ (myenv) conda install -c conda-forge spacy
```

After you install all these libraries, make sure they are in your package list

```
    $ (myenv) conda list
```

If you see libraries in your package list, you are good to go.

Comment: this works fine for me. it does show me flask and spacy in the list

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the path of your python and pip executable is the one of your conda environment? i.e.:

```
$ (myenv) which python
XXXX/XXXXX/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/python
$ (myenv) which pip
XXXX/XXXXX/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/pip
```

If that is not the case, it might be a path issue, which can happen if you prepend something to your `PATH` after activating the environment.